# Programmatically detect if attribute of `theme()` function has been set to `element_blank()` on ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an existing ggplot object from which I've removed the y title:

```r
library("ggplot")

gg = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Now I want to write a function `has_y_title()` that tells me if I've set the y
title to be `element_blank()`.

```r
has_y_title = function(gg) {
  
  # what code goes here?
  
  # returns TRUE or FALSE
}
```

The reason I want this is because without it the function below won't respect
the fact that, for this plot, I don't want a y title. Instead, it will grab the
column name that was mapped to the y axis, apply `format_text` to it, and add
it to the plot:

```r
myfunc = function(gg) {
  # if (has_y_title(gg)) {
    gg$labels$y <- format_text(gg$labels$y)
  # }
}
```

I want to apply `format_text` only when a y title was intended to be seen. I've
tried various things to determine whether `element_blank()` was used to remove
the y title, but to no avail - I'm sure this info must exist somewhere in the
structure of the ggplot object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for this example, you can use

```
has_y_title = function(gg) {
  !("element_blank" %in% attributes(gg$theme$axis.title.y)$class)
}
```

I'm not an expert of ggplot internals--there may very well be a more robust or general way.

I found this through poking, I put `gg$` in my RStudio console and the auto-complete options included "theme", so I tab-completed that and added a `$`, `gg$theme$` offered "axis.title.y" as the only option. `gg$theme$axis.title.y` didn't have any further sub-elements, so I looked at the object and it had `"element_blank"` in its class attribute.

Comment: Great thank you!  (I didn't think to ask GPT until after posting here, it offered this solution `title_blank <- identical(gg$theme$axis.title.y, ggplot2::element_blank())`). I then showed it yours and it concluded you did a better job... so really I should be giving a +2 here.

Answer (score 2):

One safe-ish way to do this would be

```
has_y_title = function(gg) {
  if ("axis.title.y" %in% names(gg$theme)) {
    return(!inherits(gg$theme$axis.title.y, "element_blank"))
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
has_y_title(gg)
```

This allows you to look for the attribute in the theme. The main ggplot code seems to use inherits to look for blank elements

Comment: This looks a bit more robust than mine.

Comment: @GregorThomas Ah. Your's should work too. I was just looking at https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/6dd9bb66116ea5531c5b649c02f7390387028087/R/theme.R#L663 as a reference

Comment: Ah I didn't see/read your answer until Gregors. +1

Answer (score 1):

So the issue with the two others answer is that they don't take into account  (1) global theme settings, (2) theme setting inheritance and (3) don't look at the leaf nodes for y-axis titles (but this can be somewhat optional).

We can solve (1) by using `theme_get()`, (2) by using `calc_element()`  and (3) by checking both `axis.title.y.left` and `axis.title.y.right`.

My proposal for your function is this one:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point()

has_y_title <- function(plot) {
  theme <- theme_get() + plot$theme # combine current theme with plot theme
  left  <- calc_element("axis.title.y.left",  theme)
  right <- calc_element("axis.title.y.right", theme)
  !(inherits(left, "element_blank") && inherits(right, "element_blank"))
}
```

Which works as follows:

```r
has_y_title(p)
#> [1] TRUE

# Any parent of y-axis title set to blank is also y-axis title blank
has_y_title(p + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()))
#> [1] FALSE
has_y_title(p + theme(axis.title = element_blank()))
#> [1] FALSE
has_y_title(p + theme(text = element_blank()))
#> [1] FALSE

# Setting the global theme works
has_y_title(p)
#> [1] TRUE
theme_set(theme_get() + theme(axis.title = element_blank()))
has_y_title(p)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# additional gnarly cases:
has_y_title(p + theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
                      axis.title.y = element_text()))
#> [1] TRUE
has_y_title(p + theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
                      axis.title.y = element_text(inherit.blank = TRUE)))
#> [1] FALSE
```

Note though that the presence of the right y-axis is conditional on using `scale_y_*(position = "right")`, `scale_y_*(guide = guide_axis(position = "right"))` or `guides(y.sec = "axis")`. However, the question is about 'tells me if I've set the y title to be element_blank()', which is not unrelated but a different question.